# Using DiskPart in a batch file to remove a disk

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, diskpart

I would like to embed diskpart command with my batch file.

for example "gpupdate.bat" is my batch file

```
@echo off
@echo off
cd: c:\windows\system32
gpupdate /force
exit
```

I want following commands to embed with above batch file (or separate batch file.)

```
diskpart
list vol
sel vol 1
remove letter=E
exit
```

I've tried the following method (detail below) but it DIDN'T WORK

create text file "removeletter.txt" with following commands

> diskpart list vol sel vol 1 remove letter=E exit

open command prompt

```
c:\users\Admin diskpart /s removeletter.txt
```

nothing happens

but when I do it manually it works

cmd -> diskpart-> list vol-> sel vol 1=> remove letter=E

Answer (score 2):

Writing your diskpart commands in a separate file should work. However, you don't need the `diskpart` command again at the top (just the commands after you call it), and the commands need to be on separate lines. And if you want this to be in a batch script, then you should call `diskpart` in a batch script that uses a text file.

`whatever.bat`

```
@echo off
diskpart /s removeletter.txt
```

`removeletter.txt`

```
list vol
sel vol 1
remove letter=E
```

Answer (score 0):

#### I would like to embed diskpart command with my batch file

You need to create a text file containing the commands for `diskpart` and then pass that to the `diskpart` commmand.

> The diskpart commands can be placed in a text file (one command per line) and used as an input file to diskpart.exe:
>
> ```
> DiskPart.exe < myscript.txt
> ```

So your files will look like the following:

**removeletter.txt**

```
list vol 
sel vol 1 
remove letter=E
```

**batch file**

```
diskpart < removeletter.txt
```

or

```
diskpart /s removeletter.txt
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dispart](http://ss64.com/nt/diskpart.html) - Disk Administration, Partition a disk.